# В каком падеже ставить прилагательное?

Tags: выбор-слов

Вот есть объявление в газете : «Купим пай / долю сельскохозяйственную (или «сельскохозяйственный» в мужском роде по слову «пай»)».

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте во множественное число и вынесите прилагательное перед первым существительным. Это лучшее решение. Либо заключите одно из существительных в скобки и согласуйте прилагательное с оставшимся.